# Return a page reference as result of action on page?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

I am using `LoadableComponent<T>` in a Selenium testing project. I have an application with a main page (modeled as `MainPage.java`) from which I go to login page (`LoginPage`). I enter some credentials and the login form is redirecting me (if credentials are valid) to the `MainPage` again, enabling some extra functionalities. Because I use `MainPage` as starting point for many tests, I had to implement `load()` method for `MainPage` with a valid URL. So if I am doing something like:

```
MainPage mainpage=new MainPage();
mainpage.get();
LoginPage loginPage=mainpage.clickLogin();
loginPage.setUser("whatever").setPassword("totally_secret");
mainpage = loginPage.clickJoin();
mainpage.get();
```

I cannot be sure if the action which directs me to the `mainpage` was succesful or not, because anyway, the last call will load the page. On the other hand if I call `clickJoin()` method without assigning the returned object to a variable, I cannot validate if the correct page is loaded and I cannot get a reference to its methods in order to continue the test. I could also make `clickJoin()` method return void, but then how do I get the reference to the new page in the test?
How should I deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why even call `mainpage.get()` after `loginPage.clickJoin()`? Wouldn't the interaction with elements on the page take you to the next/previous one?

In general, you should be able to interact with the `mainPage` object returned from `clickJoin()` right away. **You should not have to call `get()` again**. If you're getting errors without it, it's probably because of the code executing too fast, without actually waiting for the page to load properly.

To avoid this, you can have the `loginPage.clickJoin()` method make sure that the main page has loaded again.

```
public MainPage clickJoin() {

    joinLink.click(); //clicking some link/button or whatever should take you to the page

    new WebDriverWait(driver, timeToWait).until(
       //here you can use the ExpectedConditions class to wait for the title 
       //to change to a specified value or something similar. There's a wide
       //variety of methods provided. Alternatively, you can implement the
       // ExpectedCondition interface yourself
    );
    return new MainPage(driver);
}
```

If the page fails to load, you'll get an exception and the test will fail.

You don't have to do it the exact same way as in the pseudocode above but a `WebDriverWait` seems like a way to make sure the right pages load when navigating between them.

Comment: You're right, not calling get and doing a wait did the trick. I was not waiting and this led me to a wrong conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I'm 100% clear on exactly what you're asking, but here's what I think I would do. Your public methods on page objects should be more representative of user operations (logging in successfully), rather than individual actions (filling in a single field).

I have added a loggedIn flag to your MainPage constructor, which may be helpful in determining which actions are/should be available

```
class MainPage {   
    public MainPage(bool loggedIn) {
      ...
    } 
}

class LoginPage {   
    public LoginPage(){
       ...
    }

    public MainPage loginExpectSuccess(string username, string password) {
        setUser(username);
        setPassword(password);
        clickJoin();

        return new MainPage(true);
    }

    public LoginPage loginExpectFailure(string username, string password) {
        setUser(username);
        setPassword(password);
        clickJoin();

        return this;
    } 

    private void setUser(string username) {
        ...
    }

    private void setPassword(string password) {
        ...
    }

    private void clickJoin() {
        ...
    }
}
```

This way, your test can be simplified to just:

```
MainPage mainpage = new MainPage(false);
LoginPage loginPage=mainpage.clickLogin();
mainpage = loginPage.loginExpectSuccess("whatever", "totally_secret");
...
mainpage.nextUserAction(); //Do whatever a logged in user should be able to do, if user is not actually logged in successfully this will fail
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this; http://sellotapetest.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/navigation-in-page-objects-returning.html?m=1

It explains how to dynamically return different page objects from the same method.

Although it has C# examples, a similar pattern can be achieved in Java